# Nextcloud integrity check issue "App not found"

Tags: php, owncloud, nextcloud

I use Nextcloud for a while (v14.0.4) and I've got an alert from the code integrity checker with an usual message :

```
Technical information
=====================
The following list covers which files have failed the integrity check. Please read
the previous linked documentation to learn more about the errors and how to fix
them.

Results
=======
- Application to check
    - EXCEPTION
        - Exception
        - App not found

Raw output
==========
Array
(
    [Application to check] => Array
        (
            [EXCEPTION] => Array
                (
                    [class] => Exception
                    [message] => App not found
                )
        )

)
```

Can someone tell me more about this error? It seems that an exception has been thrown during check script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that an integrity check was performed on a not existing or installed app. This can happen when your, for example, run `occ integrity:check-app not_existing_app`. 
To remove the error, re-check the integrity by clicking the `Rescan...` link on the admin settings page:
[image]

For reference the [latest docs of the integrity can be found here](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/stable/admin_manual/issues/code_signing.html?highlight=integrity)